# Issue with jQuery returning a value from a <select> box

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I'm using jquery to get value from a select box so I can than post it to a php script via ajax. The issue is that I get an "undefined" value all the time, where as I expect it to be a value from a `<selec>` list.

Here is an example (select a value from category list and click submit) : http://jsfiddle.net/Rug9S/1/

as you can see no matter what value is selected you get the "undefined" one.

**HTML**

```
<form name="create" method="post" action="">
            <fieldset>
                <select name="category" id="sc_category">
                    <option value="Select a category" selected="">Select a category</option>
                    <option value="Love">Love</option>
                    <option value="Work">Work</option>
                    <option value="Sex">Sex</option>
                    <option value="Money">Money</option>
                    <option value="Kids">Kids</option>
                    <option value="Health">Health</option>
                    <option value="Friends">Friends</option>
                    <option value="Education">Education</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select><span id="sc_info">Choose the most relevant category for your story.</span><br />
                <label class="error" for="category" id="category_error">Please select a category</label><br />



                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />   
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

**java script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Story Form
    $('.error').hide();
    $(".button").click(function() {

        $('.error').hide();
        var category = $("input#sc_category").val();
        if (category == "") {
            $("label#category_error").show();
            $("input#sc_category").focus();
            return false;
        }

        var dataString = 'category=' + category;
        alert(dataString);
        return false;

    });
});
```

I only included select element in a form ass all other elements (input/textareas...) work fine.

Comment: $("input#sc_category").val(); <--- is it a SELECT, not an INPUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sc_category is not of type "input", it is of type select.

Use:
      $("#sc_category").val(); 
or
      $("select#sc_category").val();

Comment: It happens to all of us! After banging our head we see our mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

To get a select value it's like this

$('#sc_category option:selected').val();

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
 var category = $("input#sc_category").val();
```

to

```
  var category = $("#sc_category").val();
```